# How to get all variables defined in the current scope/symbol table?

Tags: php, debugging, scope

Is there a function and/or object and/or extension in PHP that will let you view all the variables defined in the current scope?  Something like:

```
var_export($GLOBALS)
```

but only showing variables in the current symbol table.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[`get_defined_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

> This function returns a multidimensional array containing a list of all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined variables, within the scope that **`get_defined_vars()`** is called.

Answer (score 23):

[get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/get_defined_vars) does exactly what you want.

> This function returns a multidimensional array containing a list of all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined variables, within the scope that **get_defined_vars()** is called.

```
>>> function test($foo) { print_r(get_defined_vars()); }
>>> test('bar');
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
```

Comment: The >>> ..., is there some command line PHP console I don't know about?

Comment: Yes, it's called phpa, you can get it here: http://david.acz.org/phpa/ You could also use the command `php -a` to run PHP interactively, but it's missing some important features.