# Is there a way to see all variables in the current scope?

Tags: php, scope

Title kinda asks it all.  I'm not referring to `$_REQUEST`, `$_SERVER` and all the pre-defined.  I just want to know if on line 400 of my program I can somehow see all the variables that have been created up to that point.

**Duplicate of:**

- [How to get all variables defined in the current scope/symbol table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717852/php-get-all-variables-defined-in-current-scope-symbol-table)

Comment: "Scope", I think, is the word you're looking for, not "namespace".

Comment: Yes, you are right.  You understood what I was asking through.  Thanks!

Comment: Namespaces? Are you working with a PHP6 build or something?? :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717852/php-get-all-variables-defined-in-current-scope-symbol-table

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`get_defined_vars()`](http://si.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)