# Retrieving local variables in PHP at runtime?

Tags: php, local-variables

If I do `print_r` in $GLOBALS I have all globals vars.

But I need something like this:

```
function foo() {
   $a = 1;
   $b = 2;
   for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++);
}

print_r(find_variables_in_function('foo')); // results: array(a => 1, b => 2, i => 10);
```

I'm trying implement a new feature in [code.google.com/p/webgrind/](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) - since this tool give me functions in run time, I can generate a chart by variables size at end of all functions called.

```
$x = 2;
$y = 3;

function foo() {
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        ;

    print_r(get_defined_vars()); // has no side effects - print null string
}
```

Comment: Why do you **need** this?  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It sounds like you have a code structure flaw. You need give us more context.

Comment: I will edit question for more details.

Comment: So, you want their values at the point of the last returned call? Remember that several instances of the same variables may exist at the same time.

Comment: Get all variables defined in current scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717852/php-get-all-variables-defined-in-current-scope-symbol-table

Comment: FYI, one indicator that PHP is not designed to give you this info, is that the Reflection mechanism for functions does not give you variables in the function body:  http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

Comment: Are you trying to track the memory usage per variable? First, this is not accurate (both may reference the same large object); second, this may differ from call to call.

Comment: Even the status of _what_ variables get defined can change from call to call.

Comment: I only can at this time analyze at end of all functions all variable size and generate a chart by size

Comment: The variable size can change from call to call

Comment: Yes I agreed, but just know this size at end will help me a lot of

Comment: Then see the linked question, AND it's a different question than your original one (from outside the function).

Comment: I see linked question and updated original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get_defined_vars() returns an array of all the variables defined in the scope in which it was called.  If you call that from within the function you will get the variables defined in that function here's the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

eg:

```
<?php 
   function foo() {
       $a = 'first';
       $b = 'second';
       $c = get_defined_vars();
       print "vars=";print_r($c);print"\n";        
   }
   foo();
?>
```

Here what it prints

```
$ php testgdvars.php
vars=Array
(
    [a] => first
    [b] => second
)
```

Comment: Execute the posted example code. get_defined_vars print only variables that in global scope.

Comment: you need to call it within the function. The variables don't exist outside the function.

Comment: Doesn't exists inside too. As sayed the example code has no side effects

Comment: I added a simple example and its output to the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but your problem may be calling in the arguments to print_r, that may be viewed as a scope.  If there is a language lawyer around they might know the answer to that.

Comment: Yes! I miss a typo in my example. Thanks, this solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the function, the variables aren't defined. Except static variables, and those are private to the function.

Why not just add a `var_dump($a,$b,$i);` to the end of the function?

Comment: Question edited to give more context